# Why is not the whole text justified?

Tags: indentation

I am new to LATEX so excuse my ignorance. 
This his how my Latex code looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\input{kvmacros}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[ceqn]{nccmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=1cm }
\makeatother

\let\oldv\verbatim
\let\oldendv\endverbatim

\def\verbatim{\par\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\oldv}
\def\endverbatim{\oldendv\egroup\fboxsep0pt \noindent\colorbox[gray]{0.95}{\usebox0}\par}




\begin{document}


  \begin{titlepage}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \draw[line width = 4pt] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-1in,1in)$);





  \end{tikzpicture}






   \centering{\fontsize{40}{50}\textbf{Obudai Egyetem}}

    %\centering{\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\textsf{Obudai Egyetem}}
    %\newline\newline
    \centering{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\textsf{Bánki Donát Gépészmérnöki kar}}\\[2in]

    \centering{\fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{}{Mobil robotok működési alapjai}}\\
    \noindent\rule{12cm}{0.4pt}\\[0.2cm]
    \centering{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\textbf{}{Spline-alapú pályatervezés}}\\[5cm]
    \centering{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\color{black!60}\textbf{}{Zsarnowszky Lóránt }}\\[0.1cm]
    \centering{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\color{black!60}\textbf{}{FET972 }}\\[2cm]
    \centering{\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont\textbf{}{2017. április 19.}}\\



  \end{titlepage}







\section*{Absztrakt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.36\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{robot_forgas.jpg}
\caption{\label{fig:kanyarodas} {\tiny Ábra 1: a differenciálhajtású robot kanyarodása.}}
\end{wrapfigure}
A differenciális hajtással rendelkező robotok a legoptimálisabban ívelt pályán közlekednek.
 Ezen pályák útvonalának a kiszámolására az általában alkalmazott, leegyszerűsített, konvencionális módszerek nem megfelelőek. A feladat során egy ilyen lágygörbéken (spline) alapuló pályatervező algoritmust mutatok be.\\

\section{Bevezetés}
\justify
Aki már próbálkozott mobil robotok útvonaltervezésével biztosan, észrevette, hogy az esetek többségében nem a legrövidebb út a leggyorsabb. Noha sok pályatervező módszer (például a hullámterjedéses) megtalálálja a legrövidebb útvonalat a célhoz, hatékonyságuk megkérdőjelezhető. Ez pontosan azért van mert a csomópontokat lineárisan vannak összekötve ezáltal a tervezett útvonal egyenesekből fog állni. Ez egy differenciál hajtású vagy szinkronizált meghajtással rendelkező robot esetében nem jelent problémát ugyanakkor a csomópontoknál előforduló éles fordulatok miatt a robotnak folyamatosan lassulnia (fékeznie) és újragyorsítani kell. Ez természetesen nem minősíthető hatékony módszernek.

\section{A választott algoritmus}
Az általam kijelölt cél hogy a differenciál hajtással rendelkező robotom a lehető leggyorsabb útszakaszt felhasználva érjen a célba. Ezáltal a robot által kiválasztott útvonal két kritériumnak kell, hogy megfeleljen:
\begin{itemize}
\item képesnek kell lennie végighaladni az útvonalon
\item a lehető legrövidebb időn belül kell a célba érkeznie [Lásd második ábra].
\end{itemize}
A feladat során bemutatom az útvonal kijelölésének a módszertanát és ellenőrzöm hogy a robot paraméterei megfelelnek-e a megadott útvonalnak.
\newpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering\includegraphics[width=7cm]{figure_1.png}
    \caption{\tiny Ábra 2: különböző útvonal algoritmusok}
\end{figure}

\section{Bezier lágygörbék}
\noindent
A Bezier eljárást Pierre Bézier francia mérnök publikálta először 1962-ben, aki az autótervezésben alkalmazta a közelítő görbéket. Paul de Casteljau 1959-ben már kifejlesztette azt az algoritmust, amelyet a mai napig is használunk a Bézier-görbék előállítására. A Bézier-görbe a számítógépes grafika mellett a robotok pályaszerkesztésénél is gyakran alkalmazott parametrikus görbe. Paraméteres módon adunk meg egy görbét, ha a görbét (vagy felületet esetleg más függvényt) definiáló olyan egyenletrendszert adunk meg, amely a görbe tetszőleges pontjának koordinátáit segédváltozók segítségével fejezik ki. A Bezier görbe egy olyan görbe amely a megadott pontokat közelíti (approximálja) az előre megadott sorrendben és nem érinti (nem interpolálja) azokat, vagy legalábbis nem mindegyiket. Például a harmadfokú Bezier görbe esetén a görbét négy pont határozza meg: egy kezdő és egy végpont és két iránypont. Negyedfokú Bezier görbe esetén már három irányponttal számolunk, és így tovább fokozható az iránypontok száma.\\
A robot útvonala több - két pont közötti - Bezier interponálásból áll. Ahhoz, hogy az útvonal egy lágygörbéje folyamatos legyen a szakaszok találkozási pontjai azonosak kell legyenek. Az útvonal tervezés során a különöböző fokszámú Bezier interpolációk alkalmazása javasolt. Ennek oka az érinteni kívánt csomópontok jelenléte. Ez természetesen az adott csomópont súlyozásával is megoldható. Ahhoz hogy lágy - a robot által könnyen azaz jelentősebb fékezés nélkül végrehajtható - útvonalszakaszaink legyenek fontos kiszámolni a pályaszakasz görbületét. Ezt az alábbi képlettel tudjuk megtenni:
\begin{ceqn}
\begin{equation*}
k = \dfrac{\dot{p_x}\ddot{p_y} - \dot{p_y}\ddot{p_x}}{(\dot{p_x^2}+\dot{p_x^2})^{3/2}}
\end{equation*}
\end{ceqn}
ahol:
\begin{itemize}
\item ${\dot{p_x}}$ és ${\ddot{p_x}}$ az útvonal első illetve másodfokú x szerinti deriváltja  
\item ${\dot{p_y}}$ és ${\ddot{p_y}}$ az útvonal első illetve másodfokú y szerinti deriváltja  
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that on the second page. I am expecting the whole text to be justified, without indentation, but I get the first and last row to be longer than all the rows between them.

Please see the picture below: [image]
Please help me if you can. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are missing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}`

Comment: `\centering` does not take an argument.

Comment: See http://math.bme.hu/latex/magyar_pre_tug2004.pdf.